# mysql query count() limit to 8

Tags: mysql

Is there away to limit the result count on this query (attached). On attached screen shot there is a result of ten counts i'm wondering if there's a way to limit or restrict the count into 8 regardless how is the result per mobile number?
thanks
[image: query count]

**UPDATE:**

Need to update my question: I need to get the latest 8 per mobile number on this query. see attached:

in the results; a mobile number 7824 has a 10 records. My goal is to get the total votes per each code but limited to 8 votes per mobile number.

[image]

Comment: That is, you do not want those with `count > 8` ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
select x.* from
```

do:

```
select case when x.count > 8 then 8 else x.count end as count, 
       x.mobile_number, 
       x.code
```

Comment: is there a way to determine the latest 8 from records?

Comment: What is latest in your output?

Answer (score 1):

Use following condition:

```
select if(count(a.id)>8,8,count(a.id)) as count
```

Comment: thanks, another question is get only the latest 8 in the records

Answer (score 1):

No need of sub-query you can get by main query as per below-

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(a.id) > 8, 8, COUNT(a.id)) AS 'count', a.mobile_number, a.shortcode AS 'code'
FROM tbl_votes AS a 
INNER JOIN tbl_members AS b ON b.mobile_number = a.mobile_number 
WHERE a.possition_id = 3 
GROUP BY a.mobile_number;
```

**Updated Answer as per Updated Query:**

```
SELECT t.id, t.mobile_number, t.shortcode AS 'code' 
FROM (SELECT t.id, t.mobile_number, t.shortcode,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category != t.mobile_number THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := t.mobile_number AS var_category
          FROM tbl_votes t
          JOIN tbl_members AS b ON b.mobile_number = t.mobile_number 
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @category := '') r     
      ORDER BY t.mobile_number,t.id DESC) X
      WHERE x.rank<=8;
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer if you get any error then create a sqlfiddle so that I can correct as I did not check it as don't have sample data.